# Function for permutation of different size vectors in R

Tags: r, function, combinations, permutation

I want to create a [function](/questions/tagged/function) which creates all possible [permutation](/questions/tagged/permutation)s of distinct vectors with elements `-1,0,1` for different size vectors.

e.g. for vectors of size 2 then i'd have `3^2 vectors`. This is easy to write down as below, but if i want to do it for vectors of size 6, i'd have to write 729.

```
x1 = c(1,1)
x2= c(1,0)
x3 = c(1,-1)
x4 = c(0,0)
x5 = c(0,1)
x6 = c(0,-1)
x7= c(-1,1)
x8 = c(-1,0)
x9 = c(-1,-1)
```

For size 3 vectors...

```
(1,1,1)
(1,1,0)
(1,1,-1)
(1,0,0)..... etc
```

Any ideas how can I make this more simplified? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach with `expand.grid`.

```
expand.grid(c(-1:1),c(-1:1),c(-1:1))
```

Or for arbitrary length vectors.

```
expand.grid(rep(list(c(-1:1)),4))
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1    -1   -1   -1   -1
2     0   -1   -1   -1
3     1   -1   -1   -1
4    -1    0   -1   -1
5     0    0   -1   -1
6     1    0   -1   -1
7    -1    1   -1   -1
8     0    1   -1   -1
9     1    1   -1   -1
10   -1   -1    0   -1
```